# How to compare string dates?

Tags: javascript

I have Dates coming back as a string and I'm displaying that on the Front End, how can I compare the dates to see which is earlier...these are just string not date objects

```
string one = "3/11/12"  
string two =  "3/13/12"
```

I know if they were date objects i could do `getTime()`. Not in this case.

Comment: what's preventing you from making them Date objects?

Comment: Why don't you convert them to actual `Date` objects and then compare?

Comment: Well if for some reason you can't convert to a date object i'd split by `/` so that you have two arrays. Then you can apply some logic to check if the years are the same to then test the months and if the months are the same then test the days etc. You get the jist

Comment: See 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already answered the problem yourself in the question:

> I know if they were date objects i could do `getTime()`

You can:

```
var stringOne = "3/11/12",
    stringTwo =  "3/13/12",
    dateOne = new Date(stringOne),
    dateTwo = new Date(stringTwo);

if (dateOne.getTime() !== dateTwo.getTime())
    console.log("Not the same...");
else
    console.log("The same...");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert strings to date objects;

`var myDate = new Date("2012/3/13");`

With that you could make the normal date operations that you want.